# How to increase zookeeper connection timeout

Tags: apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

My `Kafka` consumer loosing connection to `Zookeeper` quite often and not able to connect due to connection timeout.

How to fix the issue?

thank you.
Below is the log.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 4000
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1223)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:155)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:129)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:89)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:71)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:181)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:129)
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:65)
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:68)
at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala:120)
at kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala)
at com.steelwedge.consumer.JobConsumer.<init>(JobConsumer.java:53)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 properties for this.

`zookeeper.session.timeout.ms`
If the consumer fails to heartbeat to zookeeper for this period of time it is considered dead and a rebalance will occur

`zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms`
The max time that the client waits while establishing a connection to zookeeper